# MongoDB 3 Java check if collection exists

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following problem:

I'm using the Java driver for MongoDB 3.

In version 2 it was possible to do DB.collectionExists(name) to check whether a collection exists in the selected database.

In version 3 with the switch from DB to MongoDatabase this method no longer exists.

How do I find out whether a collection exists inside a database? I tried to iterate over the collections with listCollectionNames() but this seems quite ineffective.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are correct. It appears as if the 3.0.x version of MongoDB driver did not port over a direct "*does collection exist?*" method to `MongoDatabase`.

As you already mentioned, one option for you is to iterate through the results of `listCollectionNames()`. While this seems ineffective, it is *very* similar to what the implementation of the `DB.collectionExists(String)` method does. The code snippet below was copied from the `DB.java` class in [mongo-java-driver source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver):

```
public boolean collectionExists(final String collectionName) {
    Set<String> collectionNames = getCollectionNames();
    for (final String name : collectionNames) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(collectionName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could also get `DB` instead of `MongoDatabase` from the `MongoClient` by calling the `getDB` method. That gives you access to the `collectionExists` method **which is deprecated**. Of course, **I do not recommend this second approach** because, as mentioned, *it is deprecated*.

As a result, go with your iteration over `listCollectionNames` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response didn't looked at the drivers code. If there is no other approach I will write myself a short function

Comment: According to the Javadoc for `getDB`, the `DB`, `DBCollection`, and `DBCursor` classes will be deprecated in the future so it's wise to use the replacements (e.g. `MongoDatabase`) now.  See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver/src/main/com/mongodb/Mongo.java

Comment: @Paul Yep! Your statement echos everything that I mentioned (bolded and italicized and linked) in my post already. I concur 100%. :)

Comment: :)  I thought you meant that just `collectionExists` was deprecated...sorry about that.  Glad we're all in violent agreement!

Comment: @Paul Lol! No violence here. :) I appreciate you bringing additional clarification for all readers!

Comment: @whyceewhite why do you use "equalsIgnoreCase" instead of "equals"? collection names are case sensitive

Comment: @zeugor The code to which you are referring (containing `equalsIngoreCase`) comes directly from MongoDB's driver source code. I'm not sure why they would ignore the case since, as you pointed out, collection names are case sensitive. But take note that Mongodb  deprecated this method.

Answer (score 22):

One alternative is to use the `MongoIterable.into` function to add these to a target ArrayList that you can call `contains("collectionName")` on.

```
boolean collectionExists = client.getDatabase("dbName").listCollectionNames()
    .into(new ArrayList<String>()).contains("collectionName")
```

Answer (score 2):

for anyone still looking:
Assuming  you have MongoDatabase instance called "db"

```
try {
        db.createCollection("myCol");
    } catch (MongoCommandException e) {
        System.err.println("Collection Exists");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post as I was trying to find out an efficient way to check if a collection exists. As I have more than 50k Collections in my database, using the `listCollectionNames()` method is extremely inefficient.

What I did was to use the `db.collection.count()` method and if it returned a non-zero value, then I would treat it as a non-existent collection. Ofcourse this is not hundred percent correct, since one could have a collection with zero entries and this approach would treat that as a non-existent collection. But for most scenarios in MongoDB, a collection makes sense only if it has at least one document. Following is a sample code,

```
public boolean isCollectionExists(DB db, String collectionName) 
{

    DBCollection table = db.getCollection(collectionName);
    return (table.count()>0)?true:false;
}
```

Comment: Great idea but as you already said, it's not guaranteed to work. By the way you can write `return table.count() > 0;` instead as this is a valid boolean expression.

Comment: @Frozn Thanks for the tip! I also wanted to clarify that it is guaranteed to work as long as you have no empty collections by design.

Comment: This doesn't really work, another work-around would be to create a collection, if it already exists it throws an exception, and therefore you can check the error, if it contains "NamespaceExists", then you know the collection is there. Otherwise use the list and contains check above, if you don't want this mildly hacky way.

Answer (score 1):

```
MongoIterable <String> collection =  database.listCollectionNames();
    for(String s : collection) {
        if(s.equals("collectionName")) {
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while searching for the exact same question. Using the newest driver, i.e.:

```
<!-- Mongo driver, GeoJson with Jackson, Gson for Mongo (Jongo) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

someone may want to use:

```
public boolean collectionExists(final String db, final String collectionName) {
    final MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase(db);
    if (database == null) {
            return false;
    }

    final MongoIterable<String> iterable = database.listCollectionNames();
    try (final MongoCursor<String> it = iterable.iterator()) {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().equalsIgnoreCase(collectionName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kiuz, seems to be something wrong with your mongoDB, maybe you had a DB with that name and removed it and it is somehow still in the meta information? If I try to do what you describe I get the correct results. Is your client connected? We are using this code snippet in production and it works just fine. I do some further testing on my side and let you know if I can somehow reproduce your description.

Comment: No worries, hope the code helped anyways! Btw. whoever downvoted a comment would be nice to solve the problem.