# MongoDB method reference print list of databases?

Tags: java, mongodb

Following this [guide](http://www.baeldung.com/java-mongodb), I am trying to print out a list of databases.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Testing MongoDB.");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("myMongoDb");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully.");

        database.getCollection("Customers");
        System.out.println("Created Customer collection successfully.");

        MongoCursor<String> dbsCursor = database.listCollectionNames().iterator();

        while(dbsCursor.hasNext()){
           System.out.println(dbsCursor.next());
        }

        database.listCollectionNames().forEach((Consumer<String>) System.out::println);
        mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().forEach((Consumer<String>) System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I tested with a regular iterator as well but only get the following output.

```
> Task :run
Testing MongoDB.
Dec 27, 2017 1:02:49 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Connect to database successfully.
Created Customer collection successfully.
Dec 27, 2017 1:02:49 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Dec 27, 2017 1:02:49 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:23}] to localhost:27017
Dec 27, 2017 1:02:49 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2474145}
Dec 27, 2017 1:02:49 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:24}] to localhost:27017
admin
config
local
```

Expected output, as per the guide, would be something like this:

```
The output will be:

local      0.000GB
myMongoDb  0.000GB
```

I'm not too sure what i'm doing wrong. Additionally, is there a way to silence the logging such that I can inspect my output easier?

Comment: According to the documentation you won't get that "expected" result because those methods return names only.

Comment: I see. Even so, I read that mongoDB will create a DB/collection if the one being 'get' doesn't exist. In this case, it seems that both collection/DB is not being shown. Is there a way to verify them in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB 3 Java check if collection exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909247/mongodb-3-java-check-if-collection-exists)

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to check if a collection exists, try this:**

```
boolean collectionExists = client.getDatabase("dbName").listCollectionNames()
.into(new ArrayList<String>()).contains("collectionName")
```