# How to add several documents using capped collection via mongodb Java driver 3.4+?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to add several document using [capped collection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/databases-collections/) and writing like:

```
// this code insert only first document using capped collection 
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
        database.createCollection("capped_collection",
                new CreateCollectionOptions().capped(true).sizeInBytes(536870912).maxDocuments(5000));

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("capped_collection");

        Document found = database.getCollection("capped_collection").find(new Document("title", title)
                .append("url", url)
                .append("img", img)
                .append("price", price)).first();

        if (found == null) {

            collection.insertOne(new Document("title", title)
                            .append("url", url)
                            .append("img", img)
                            .append("price", price));

            mongoClient.close();
    }
```

In this case capped collection gives me to insert only first document and that's all (I want several not one). If I create normal collection I can insert several docs. Why it happens?

```
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("normal_collection");

        Document found = database.getCollection("normal_collection").find(new Document("title", title)
                .append("url", url)
                .append("img", img)
                .append("price", price)).first();

        if (found == null) {
            collection.insertOne(new Document("title", title)
                            .append("url", url)
                            .append("img", img)
                            .append("price", price));

            mongoClient.close();
        }
```

In this way I can insert several documents using normal collection.

As I understand properly, there is no difference in the code between inserting documents into a capped collection and a normal collection, but in fact I have different results.

**Updated:**
*Just tried manually to add docs in capped collection via powershell*

In powershell manually could be like:
[image]

Documents looks like (as test):
[image]

Correct me, please, if I'm wrong. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Veeram, can you help me here or someone else?

Comment: I don't see the code where you are inserting multiple documents. You are using `insertOne` which will only insert one document.

Comment: @Veeram, yes, because method which has this collection of documents parse each good and add in database separately via `insertOne` method. Okay, I will improve code for you.

Comment: @Veeram, added as "fully code"

Comment: If I use normal collection everything is fine and each new document added to database perfectly, but when I will create capped collection instead of normal ```database.createCollection("capped_collection", new CreateCollectionOptions().capped(true).sizeInBytes(536870912).maxDocuments(5000));```, in collection will insert only one doc. I can't undertand why? What is the difference between them?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is going on. Is the single document the last document that you insert ? Btw you don't have to create client and collection  for every insertion. You can move that code outside of addFeed method.

Comment: @Veeram, I parse each good via method run() then call method addFeed() and pass parameters to this method that will create document for each good and add in database. In database via capped collection will insert only first document, just first. If I use normal collection in my database will insert each good, not only first.

Comment: Not sure..Can you create a capped collection from mongo shell instead of java code and see if you can insert multiple documents ? Just trying to debug.

Comment: @Veeram, just tried, yes, I can manually insert multiple documents in capped collection. But I need to do that via Java code  somehow.

Comment: What happens when you just insert the documents without the found part ?

Comment: @Veeram, added screen as result in my question, when I added 2 documents via powershell in capped collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve it. I needed [to check for an existing collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706871/8370915):

```
boolean collectionExists = mongoClient.getDatabase("db_feed").listCollectionNames()
                .into(new ArrayList<>()).contains("capped_collection");

        if(!collectionExists) {
            database.createCollection("capped_collection",
                    new CreateCollectionOptions().capped(true).sizeInBytes(327).maxDocuments(1).autoIndex(true));
        }
```